# How to sort Bing Custom Search API v7 results?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-search

I read in the Bing blogs that BIng search APIs provide improved performance, new sorting and filtering options. But I am not  seeing any documentation on implementing the same on the Bing custom search APIs.

Is this feature currently available or slated for future  release?

Answer (score 0):

Bing Custom Search results are ranked by relevance. For sorting by date, you can try **sortBy:Date** parameter.

Comment: Please confirm if this is a query parameter? I am not able to see any reference to this implmentation. My end point looks as below:                                             https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bingcustomsearch/v7.0/search?q=bing&customconfig=<<value>>&mkt=en-US&safesearch=Moderate&count=10&offset=0

Comment: You could try appending appending **&sortBy:Date** to the URL. It works for other Bing APIs, but I haven't tried for the Bing Custom Search API. If you don't see difference in results, this parameter is not supported.

Comment: Hi Ronak!! Thanks for the guidance. I tried with &sortBy:Date appended to my API  and also &sortby=Date. Both did not sort the results. Just to confirm, does it has to be  **&sortBy:Date** or  **&sortBy=Date**

Comment: Both should work, but if you don't see any changes in results - this parameter is not supported for the Bing Custom Search.